# How to select a svg inside a div in d3?

Tags: javascript, d3.js, svg

I have appended a SVG inside a div. Following is the code for this:

```
var metricDiv = d3.select("#metric4");
var metricSVG = metricDiv.append("svg")
    .attr("width", width)
    .attr("height", height)
    .attr("id", "metricmap")
    .call(zoom)
    .append("g");
//create a place holder rectangle to keep floats inline
var svgContainer = d3.select("body").append("svg")
    .attr("width", width)
    .attr("height", width)
    .attr("id", "placeholder");
d3.json("img/defense_data.json", function (error, map) {
    if (error) return console.error(error);
    var projection = d3.geo.mercator()
        .center([7.612337603149424, 51.96211781909236])
        .scale(3000000);
    //.translate(0,0);
    var path = d3.geo.path()
        .projection(projection);
    metricSVG.selectAll(".city_block_landmarks")
        .data(topojson.feature(map, map.objects.city_block_landmarks).features)
        .enter().append("path")
        .attr("class", function (d) {
            //console.log(d.properties.class)
            return d.properties.classfeature;
        })
        .attr("id", function (d) {
            //console.log(d.id)
            return d.id;
        })
        .attr("d", path);
    metricSVG.selectAll(".hidden_landmarks")
        .data(topojson.feature(map, map.objects.hidden_landmarks).features)
        .enter().append("path")
        .attr("class", function (d) {
            //console.log(d.properties.class)
            return d.properties.classfeature;
        })
        .attr("id", function (d) {
            //console.log(d.id)
            return d.id;
        })
        .attr("d", path);
    metricSVG.selectAll(".botanica_mid_polygons")
        .data(topojson.feature(map, map.objects.botanica_mid_polygons).features)
        .enter().append("path")
        .attr("class", function (d) {
            //console.log(d.properties.class)
            return d.properties.classfeature;
        })
        .attr("id", function (d) {
            //console.log(d.id)
            return d.id;
        })
        .attr("d", path);
    metricSVG.selectAll(".streets_linear_features")
        .data(topojson.feature(map, map.objects.streets_linear_features).features)
        .enter().append("path")
        .attr("class", function (d) {
            //console.log(d.properties.class)
            return d.properties.classfeature;
        })
        .attr("id", function (d) {
            //console.log(d.id)
            return d.id;
        })
        .attr("d", path);
});
```

Now, I want to select everything that is appended inside the div `#metric4` and not the div itself. I know that we usually do this using the `d3.select()` function but I cannot figure out what to write inside the bracket of the selection function to select all the stuff appended to the div. Can anyone help me out with this one?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to select everything inside the element you can use `*` as the selector.

`d3.select("#metric4").selectAll("*")`

This will select everything from within that div, and you can continue to use d3 method chaining to do what you want with the selection.